# Facebook Review for API only App

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am working on building Facebook integration from an internal company application to allow for creating Ads on Facebook using their Marketing API. In order to accomplish this, it appears creating an "App" is a necessity to be able to get access to their API. This App will ONLY be used for API communication and should never be needed by an end user on Facebook.

My problem is the App is currently in development mode and I need to submit it for review in order to qualify for a higher level of API access to not be as rate limited on the number of requests. Since this App is only used for API access is there a way to keep it hidden from the general public on Facebook? It should never be needed to be accessed directly from any random Facebook account, only from the SDK we are using interally.

Comment: Of course it needs to be accessed by an end user. How else would you get access to ads? The end user that have access to those ads needs to grant permission to your app to access the ads.

Comment: @WizKid Sorry I should have clarified. The end user I guess in this case is the SDK used internally to access and manage all of the ads in our ads account. That does have access and is able to access things fine. What I meant to say by end user is just a random Facebook user searching and finding our app.

Comment: Did you find out the answer to this question? We are also building an internal-only app. I got around the rate limit by creating multiple versions of the app, and then writing code to switch to the next app when the previous one is rate-limited, but it's a pretty awful workaround.

Comment: @SalahatSoapHope We were able to work around this by submitting the app for a higher access level, ultimately I believe we bumped it up to Standard API Access. I wasn't sure if that would work for an internal only app, but it seemed to pass Facebooks checks.